# Can't lauch Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

I have a problem with Android Studio.
When I install the last version, if I try to launch, I have a white window with "start failed" and I have to close it with the task manager.

So I tried with version 4.1 and I get this message:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.android.tools.idea.welcome.install.Haxm
    at com.android.tools.idea.updater.configure.ToolComponentsPanel.<clinit>(ToolComponentsPanel.java:65)
    at com.android.tools.idea.updater.configure.SdkUpdaterConfigPanel.$$$setupUI$$$(SdkUpdaterConfigPanel.java)
    at com.android.tools.idea.updater.configure.SdkUpdaterConfigPanel.<init>(SdkUpdaterConfigPanel.java:211)
    at com.android.tools.idea.updater.configure.SdkUpdaterConfigurable.createComponent(SdkUpdaterConfigurable.java:129)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.ex.ConfigurableWrapper.createComponent(ConfigurableWrapper.java:162)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.ex.ConfigurableCardPanel.lambda$createConfigurableComponent$4(ConfigurableCardPanel.java:109)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:894)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.ReadAction.compute(ReadAction.java:61)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.ex.ConfigurableCardPanel.createConfigurableComponent(ConfigurableCardPanel.java:105)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.ex.ConfigurableCardPanel.lambda$create$0(ConfigurableCardPanel.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:894)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.ReadAction.compute(ReadAction.java:61)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.ex.ConfigurableCardPanel.create(ConfigurableCardPanel.java:53)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.newEditor.ConfigurableEditor$1.create(ConfigurableEditor.java:51)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.newEditor.ConfigurableEditor$1.create(ConfigurableEditor.java:48)
    at com.intellij.ui.CardLayoutPanel.createValue(CardLayoutPanel.java:73)
    at com.intellij.ui.CardLayoutPanel.select(CardLayoutPanel.java:101)
    at com.intellij.ui.CardLayoutPanel.lambda$null$0(CardLayoutPanel.java:117)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$2.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:201)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:831)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.lambda$invokeLater$4(ApplicationImpl.java:310)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.doRun(FlushQueue.java:80)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.runNextEvent(FlushQueue.java:128)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.flushNow(FlushQueue.java:46)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue$FlushNow.run(FlushQueue.java:184)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:764)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:734)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:974)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:847)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$null$8(IdeEventQueue.java:449)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:730)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$9(IdeEventQueue.java:448)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:831)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:496)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:190)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:235)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1077)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl$MyDialog.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:708)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:437)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.doShow(DialogWrapper.java:1685)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.show(DialogWrapper.java:1644)
    at com.intellij.ide.actions.ShowSettingsUtilImpl.showSettingsDialog(ShowSettingsUtilImpl.java:124)
    at com.intellij.ide.actions.ShowSettingsUtilImpl.showSettingsDialog(ShowSettingsUtilImpl.java:97)
    at com.intellij.ide.actions.ShowSettingsUtilImpl.showSettingsDialog(ShowSettingsUtilImpl.java:89)
    at com.android.tools.idea.updater.configure.RunSdkConfigAction.actionPerformed(RunSdkConfigAction.java:75)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.wizard.SdkQuickfixUtils.showAndroidSdkManager(SdkQuickfixUtils.java:137)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.wizard.SdkQuickfixUtils.showSdkMissingDialog(SdkQuickfixUtils.java:132)
    at com.android.tools.idea.actions.AndroidNewProjectAction.actionPerformed(AndroidNewProjectAction.kt:41)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:280)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.invokeAction(ActionUtil.java:443)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.invokeAction(ActionUtil.java:428)
    at com.intellij.ui.components.labels.ActionLink$1.linkSelected(ActionLink.java:46)
    at com.intellij.ui.components.labels.LinkLabel.doClick(LinkLabel.java:143)
    at com.intellij.ui.components.labels.ActionLink.doClick(ActionLink.java:55)
    at com.intellij.ui.components.labels.LinkLabel$MyMouseHandler.mouseReleased(LinkLabel.java:331)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6550)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3325)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6315)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4899)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4721)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4721)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:766)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:739)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:737)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:736)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:974)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchMouseEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:912)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:844)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$null$8(IdeEventQueue.java:449)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:741)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$9(IdeEventQueue.java:448)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:831)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:502)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

After that if I click on **"nexproject"** I receive **"Your Android SDK is missing, out of date or corrupted."**
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKTJH.png)

I tried all the day but now, i'm really lost...
Please can you help me?
You will save my weekend.

I have jdk-17 installed.
Here my configuration: AMD Ryzen 7 5800X 8-Core Processor 3.80 GHz
64 bits, processeur x64 Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

You're not alone... I decided to hit that update button from the notification in Arctic Fox about 4 hours ago. I've uninstalled and re-installed several times. Along the way I noticed that Android Studio 4.2 will install and run. But not Arctic Fox.

[image]

Comment: I just tried and evend with 4.2 i have the same screen but without the internal error. Just the "start failed"

Comment: I got my problem resolved after a lot of re-installs. At some point (while it was still working) I had changed the SDK install point. I'd deleted that already. Before deleting it I had 4 errors rather than just the 1. At any rate I found a reference to that folder in my environment variables (Windows 10). I deleted that, along with all of the other user files I'd been deleting all along for each re-install. Then re-installed and it's finally happy again. I'm new to Android Studio, so far it seems like a lot of fairy dust and magic sprinkles all over the place. I hope you find your gremlin!!!

Comment: Happy for you guy. I created a new local account. And android studio work. Maybe like you a problem with variable path. I don' know. Well i have my solution.